# android and itext

Tags: android

I want to display pdf in android with next/previous and zoom effect,i check out the already exits the lib for that but it is too slow then, I move to itext.
  I install the jar file and code to get the total number pages.
  But question how i can display the pdf,i mean to say take the text view,then how i will manage the background of the pdf,so there are many query.
  Can anybody help me out if some-one have gone through the steps

Thanks in advance and every suggestion wel come here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know iText is not meant to *display* PDF files, but to manipulate (as in: read, change, write) them. Viewing is not possible.

Comment: thank you,but there is any way i can view pdf inside the app?

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
    private void openFile(String path) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    File f = new File(path);
    String type = FileUtil.getMIMEType(f.getName());
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), type);
    startActivity(intent);
}

    public static String getMIMEType(String name) {
    String type = "";
    String end = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, name.length()).toLowerCase();
    end = end.toLowerCase();
    if (end.equals("apk")) {
        return "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
    } else if (end.equals("mp4") || end.equals("avi") || end.equals("3gp")
            || end.equals("rmvb")) {
        type = "video";
    } else if (end.equals("m4a") || end.equals("mp3") || end.equals("mid") || end.equals("xmf")
            || end.equals("ogg") || end.equals("wav")) {
        type = "audio";
    } else if (end.equals("jpg") || end.equals("gif") || end.equals("png")
            || end.equals("jpeg") || end.equals("bmp")) {
        type = "image";
    } else if (end.equals("txt") || end.equals("log") || end.equals("sql")) {
        type = "text";
    }else {
        type = "*";
    }
    type += "/*";
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a pdf viewer such as Adobe Reader onto your device (it is available onn Android MarketPlace).  Then from use this function in your app you can use an intent to open the pdf

```
public void OpenPDF(File f)
{
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: yes, but i want to open it side the app,i have done with it using the vudroid lib.